# Data Transformation in R for Panel Regression

Tags: r, panel, regression, reshape

I really need your help regarding a problem which may seem easy to solve for you.

Currently I work on a project which involves some panel-regressions. I have several large csv-files (up to 12 million entries per sheet) which are formatted as in the picture attached, whereas the columns (V1, V2) are individuals and the rows (1, 2, 3) are time identifiers.

In order to use the `plm()`-function I need all these files to convert to the following data structure:

```
ID Time X1 X2
1 1 x1 x2
1 2 x1 x2
1 ... ... ...
2 1 x1 x2
2 2 ... ...
```

I really struggle with this transformation and I'm really frustrated right now i.e. where do I get the identifier and the time index from?
Would really appreciate if you could provide me with information how to solve this problem.

If my question is not clear to you, just ask.

Best regards and thanks in advance

[image]

The output should look like as follows:

[image]

Comment: This is how it should look like: http://imgur.com/uAHL07w

Comment: You can use `reshape2` package

Comment: Thank you for your answer
And how would the code look like since I don't have Time or Identifier Variables?

Comment: You need to `dput` the sample data for reproducibility

Comment: http://www.file-upload.net/download-8028487/example.html
That's one of the files. They all have a similar structure.
Each column is a time series for an individual

Comment: I will post the answer for a small data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 mydata<-structure(list(V1 = 10:13, V2 = 21:24, V3 = c(31L, 32L, 3L, 34L
    )), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -4L))

> mydata
  V1 V2 V3
1 10 21 31
2 11 22 32
3 12 23  3
4 13 24 34
```

The following code can be used for your data without changing anything. For illustration, I used just the above data. I used the base R `reshape` function

```
long <- reshape(mydata, idvar = "time", ids = row.names(mydata),
                times = names(mydata), timevar = "id",
                varying = list(names(mydata)),v.names="value", new.row.names = 1:((dim(mydata)[2])*(dim(mydata)[1])),direction = "long")

> long
   id value time
1  V1    10    1
2  V1    11    2
3  V1    12    3
4  V1    13    4
5  V2    21    1
6  V2    22    2
7  V2    23    3
8  V2    24    4
9  V3    31    1
10 V3    32    2
11 V3     3    3
12 V3    34    4
long$id<-substr(long$id,2,4) # 4 is used to take into account your 416 variables
myout<-long[,c(1,3,2)]
> myout
   id time value
1   1    1    10
2   1    2    11
3   1    3    12
4   1    4    13
5   2    1    21
6   2    2    22
7   2    3    23
8   2    4    24
9   3    1    31
10  3    2    32
11  3    3     3
12  3    4    34
```

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. Please consider accepting the answer so that future user may find it helpful.

Comment: +1. `prod(dim(mydata))` is much more legible than `(dim(mydata)[2])*(dim(mydata)[1])`. It seems to me that the `time` and `id` variables are the opposite of what I would have expected though.

Comment: @Metrics, you might also want to check out my "splitstackshape" package. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18565337/1270695).

Comment: @ Ananda: You are right. It's just the opposite here. I will look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative: Use `Stacked` from my "splitstackshape" package.

Here it is applied on @Metrics's sample data:

```
# install.packages("splitstackshape")
library(splitstackshape)
Stacked(cbind(id = 1:nrow(mydata), mydata), 
        id.vars="id", var.stubs="V", sep = "V")
#     id .time_1  V
#  1:  1       1 10
#  2:  1       2 21
#  3:  1       3 31
#  4:  2       1 11
#  5:  2       2 22
#  6:  2       3 32
#  7:  3       1 12
#  8:  3       2 23
#  9:  3       3  3
# 10:  4       1 13
# 11:  4       2 24
# 12:  4       3 34
```

It would be very fast if your data are large. Here are the speeds for the 12MB dataset you linked to. The sorting is different but the data are the same.

It still isn't faster than `stack` though (but at some point, `stack` starts to slow down).

See the `system.time`s below:

#### `reshape()`

```
system.time(out <- reshape(x, idvar = "time", ids = row.names(x),
                           times = names(x), timevar = "id",
                           varying = list(names(x)), 
                           v.names="value",
                           new.row.names = 1:prod(dim(x)), 
                           direction = "long"))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   53.11    0.00   53.11 
head(out)
#   id        value time
# 1 V1  0.003808635    1
# 2 V1 -0.018807416    2
# 3 V1  0.008875447    3
# 4 V1  0.001148695    4
# 5 V1 -0.019365004    5
# 6 V1  0.012436560    6
```

#### `Stacked()`

```
system.time(out2 <- Stacked(cbind(id = 1:nrow(x), x), 
                            id.vars="id", var.stubs="V", 
                            sep = "V"))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.30    0.00    0.29 

out2
#           id .time_1            V
#      1:    1       1  0.003808635
#      2:    1      10 -0.014184635
#      3:    1     100 -0.013341843
#      4:    1     101  0.006784138
#      5:    1     102  0.006463707
#     ---                          
# 963868: 2317      95  0.009569451
# 963869: 2317      96  0.002497771
# 963870: 2317      97  0.009202519
# 963871: 2317      98  0.017007545
# 963872: 2317      99 -0.002495842
```

#### `stack()`

```
system.time(out3 <- cbind(id = 1:nrow(x), stack(x)))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.09    0.00    0.09
head(out3)
#   id       values ind
# 1  1  0.003808635  V1
# 2  2 -0.018807416  V1
# 3  3  0.008875447  V1
# 4  4  0.001148695  V1
# 5  5 -0.019365004  V1
# 6  6  0.012436560  V1
```

Comment: My observation is that the `stack` is superfast because it is using `data.table`. Is that correct?

Comment: @Metrics, `Stacked` (my function) uses `unlist` in `data.table`. `stack` is pure base R.